# What's the name and time complexity of this sorting algo?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

So I have a list of objects. All of the same type. Let's call it Foo. 
Foo has a property "value" and I'd like to sort by that value.
I have implemented the algorithm in Java. It's generic and I provide two examples. One uses integers and the other uses enum constants as the type of the values.

The algorithm simply iterated over all possible values and then iterates the input list for each such value. All elements with the same value are added to the result list. And that's it.

If there are 11 values then it will iterate the list 11 times. So time complexity would be O(11*n). But 11 is a constant, so it really is O(n), which is quite good for a sorting algorithm. Even if there could be billions of values it would still be O(n). Is assumption this correct?

I actually found something like this in some code I had to work on. It took me some time just to figure out that the code does, because I wouldn't expect anyone to actually implement a sorting algorithm for no good reason. The code was written by someone who didn't know that Java allows you to sort by `Collections.sort(myList, Comparator.comparing(Foo::getValue))`.

At first I thought that this is a horrible way to sort a list, but then I realized that it's actually quite fast and even *stable*. But it's not *in place*. And I was wondering what the name of that algorithm is.

The performance of common algorithms, such as quick sort, is probably still much better when tested on actual data. So I wonder if this one is ever used.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class SortAlgo {
  /**
   * Sorts a list. The sort is stable. 
   * The input won't be changed. A new list is returned instead.
   * 
   * @param list
   *          The list to be sorted.
   * @param values
   *          The possible values of the field used for the sorting.
   * @param get
   *          A function to get the value.
   * @return A new, sorted list.
   */
  public static <T, V> List<T> sort(final List<T> list, final List<V> values,
      final Function<T, V> get) {
    final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    for (final V v : values)
      for (final T t : list)
        if (get.apply(t) == v)
          result.add(t);
    assert result.size() == list.size();
    return result;
  }

  static class Foo1 {
    public static final int MIN_VALUE = 0;
    public static final int MAX_VALUE = 10;
    final private int value;

    public Foo1(final int value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
      return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return Integer.toString(this.value);
    }
  }

  static class Foo2 {
    public static enum Value {
      A, B, C, D, E;
    }

    final private Value value;

    public Foo2(final Value value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public Value getValue() {
      return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return this.value.name();
    }
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final List<Foo1> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    final Random rng = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      list1.add(new Foo1(rng.nextInt(Foo1.MAX_VALUE + 1)));

    final List<Integer> values1 = IntStream.rangeClosed(Foo1.MIN_VALUE, Foo1.MAX_VALUE).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    final List<Foo1> sorted1 = sort(list1, values1, Foo1::getValue);

    System.out.println(sorted1);

    // -------------------------

    final List<Foo2> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    final Foo2.Value[] enums = Foo2.Value.values();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      list2.add(new Foo2(enums[rng.nextInt(enums.length)]));

    final List<Foo2.Value> values2 = Arrays.asList(enums);
    final List<Foo2> sorted2 = sort(list2, values2, Foo2::getValue);

    System.out.println(sorted2);

  }

}
```

Comment: Just a hint: In your computation of the complexity, what is `n`?

Comment: Is that a hint or a question? `n` is the size of the list. It's the size if the input. Maybe it would be correct to also have `m` for the number of possible values. So complexity is `O(n*m)`?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the point! :)

Comment: So if `m < log n` then this is better than `O(n log n)`. Right? That's nearly always the case. But there's a worst case scenario where `m==n => O(nm) == O(n^2)`. And best case is `O(n)`. 
Doesn't this algo have a name?

Answer (score 0):

It's essentially a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), which is O(n), but with an extra loop instead of storing the values in an array and only looping through it once.

Comment: But there's no counting in this algorithm.

Comment: Suppose you're looking for all the 1s first. You could just count them and then output that number of 1s at the end. You're just writing them out as you come to them, but the effect is the same.